# IPython: Does "%matplotlib inline" required before importing matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

I am using IPython. Got confused that the codes can't execute if I don't add

```
%matplotlib
```

before

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Could someone enlighten me by explaining why the magic function call in IPython is needed for matplotlib usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's needed because normally matplotlib opens additional windows for graphs using a default toolkit. The %inline lets you load graphs in the IPython notebook, instead of using an external toolkit.